# Vagrant up problem: sh: netsh: command not found

Tags: vagrant

I am using macOS Mojave. After I installed VirtualBox and Vagrant, I tried "vagrant up". However, I got following strange error:

```
Dir: VA $vagrant up
sh: netsh: command not found
sh: cscript: command not found
It seems that you don't have the privileges to change 
the firewall rules. NFS will not work without that 
firewall changes. Execute the following commands via 
cmd as administrator:
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule 
name="VagrantWinNFSd-1.4.0" dir="in" action=allow 
protocol=any 
program="\Users\Ten\.vagrant.d\gems\2.4.4\gems\vagrant 
...
```

It seems **netsh** and **cscript** command belong to Windows. However, I am using macOS and I am sure my VirtualBox and Vagrant are for macOS.

Can any one help me with this question? Thanks!

=====================       Updated     ===================

At last I solved this problem. However I am sorry I forgot I raised the question here and even worse I forgot how I solved it.

The only thing I remembered is, installing VirtualBox first and then Vagrant is important. And reinstallation may help.

Hope this can help a bit.

Comment: Same issue here, but not sure if that is the problem. My `vagrant up` command finally fails on `in `nfs_export': wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 5)`. Even if I disabled nfs

Comment: Did you install VirtualBox before installing Vagrant? Issues like this arise if you install Vagrant before VirtualBox

Comment: I didn't remember. But you are right this is very possible to be the reason. Thanks! @Kevin

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue on macOS Sierra (10.12.6). I resolved it after finding that I had the plugin **vagrant-winnfsd** installed.

To uninstall, I ran the command:

```
vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-winnfsd
```